# Subnetting Doubt

Tags: subnet

I have two PCs connected to a single switch. Default gateway is not configured for both.

### PC1

IP Address  - 10.3.0.1
Subnet Mask - 255.255.248.0

### PC2

IP Address  - 10.3.4.1
Subnet Mask - 255.255.252.0

Will they communicate (PING) with each other? As per my understanding, PC1 can ping PC2 successfully while PC2 cannot ping PC1 because PC1 is on a different network. Is it true?

regards,
Abhilash

Answer (score 3):

For a ping to work both hosts need to be able to send **and** receive packets from each other. One sends an echo request to the second host, which the second host upon receiving transforms into an echo response that it sends to the original host. Two packets, one in each direction.

At the very least you will see some odd behaviors in this setup anyway as, unless you've specified otherwise the two hosts will have different ideas of what the broadcast address is. I'd steer well clear of anything crazy like this, even if "it works".

It doesn't provide any security at all (if that was the intention) and it will lead to odd, hard to diagnose problems in the future.